# How to make Angular Ivy + Angular Universal work?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ivy

I'm having an error when I try to have Ivy + Angular Universal in my project.

I only have this error when I use Angular in Ivy mode (when I set `enableIvy` to false in my `tsconfig.app.json` I can successfully build my app).

Here are the steps to reproduce my problem :

**1. New project with Ivy**

`ng new test-angular --enableIvy`

**2. Add Angular Universal**

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject test-angular`

**3. When I do ng build I get an error**

`ERROR in Node does not exist: "path_to/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine"`

My ng --version output is :

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.0
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.801.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.801.0
@angular-devkit/core                       8.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                           8.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine                8.1.1
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.1.1
@schematics/angular                        8.1.0
@schematics/update                         0.801.0
rxjs                                       6.4.0
typescript                                 3.4.5
webpack                                    4.35.2
```

If I delete these lines in `main.server.ts` file (a file generated in step 2)

```
export { ngExpressEngine } from "@nguniversal/express-engine";
export { provideModuleMap } from "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader";
```

The commands `ng build`, `ng serve` works but I still can use SSR (`npm run serve:ssr` fails with `TypeError: provideModuleMap is not a function` because of the line I've deleted I guess ...).

Thank you =)

Comment: this will be available in Angular 9, they mentioned at ng-conf 2019 that Ivy is in opt-preview and cannot work with SSR

Comment: Yup, I've created a GitHub issue : [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31522#event-2534645867).

It works now on Angular 9

Answer (score 2):

We just released official support for Ivy & NG9 (just be forwarned that ng9 is still in `rc` (release candidate), so a few things might change with Angular before the final release).

#### You can read the full article & announcement here on the **Trilon blog: [Angular Universal v9: What's New?](https://trilon.io/blog/angular-universal-v9-whats-new)**

**To summarize getting it setup:**

- Make sure your Angular application is already upgraded to the latest v9 (RC)
- Install the latest (RC) Universal schematics `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@next`
- If you're coming from an existing Universal schematic v8 (express-engine or hapi-engine) upgrade via "ng update" ie:
  `ng update @nguniversal/express-engine —-next`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue just after updating my APP to A9